# TypeError: createWorker is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, tesseract.js

const worker = new createWorker({
^

TypeError: createWorker is not a constructor

I'm having this error every time, I have changed from TesseractWorker to createWorker but I'm still having this issue.

Package:
"tesseract.js": "2.1.4"

Comment: `const worker = createWorker(...)`

Comment: Thank you very much it worked